# Symfony2: Encode Password before login_check

Tags: symfony, authentication, hash

i`ve followed the guide ([Encoding the User's Password](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#book-security-encoding-user-password) and [How to customize your Form Login](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html)) from the symfony homepage.

New created users will be stored to the database with an encrypted password (encryption occurs in the controller). But when i try to login, with a user from the database, the authentication fails due comparison of the raw password coming from the login form and the encrypted one from the db.

So my question is how i can encrypt the password coming the login form before the login_check? Would it be a proper solution to extend e.g. *DaoAuthenticationProvider*? Or is my approach completely wrong as i keep the encryption separated from the model?

**security.yml:**

```
security:
   encoders:
       MyCorp\UserBundle\Entity\User:
           algorithm:          sha512
           encode_as_base64:   true
           iterations:         1000
providers:
       db_users:
           entity: {class: MyCorpUserBundle:User, property: username}
```

**User controller (example of encryption on creation):**

```
/**
  * Creates a new User entity.
  *
  * @Route("/", name="user_create")
  * @Method("POST")
  * @Template("MyCorpUserBundle:User:new.html.twig")
  */
 public function createAction(Request $request)
 {
     $entity = new User();
     $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
     $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($entity);
     $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
     $form->handleRequest($request);

     if ($form->isValid()) {
         $pasword = $encoder->encodePassword($entity->getPassword(), $user->getSalt());
         $entity->setPassword($pasword);

         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
         $em->persist($entity);
         $em->flush();

         return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
     }

     return array(
         'entity' => $entity,
         'form'   => $form->createView(),
     );
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think that raw password is used? Raw password is indeed sent over the wire, but to verify the password Symfony uses the same encoder you've used to encode it.

It uses the other method of the PasswordEncoderInterface - [isPasswordValid()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/PasswordEncoderInterface.php#L40), which accepts a raw password, not encoded.

There must be something else wrong with your app. Btw, is your salt generated?

Comment: Nvermind, thanks for the hint with _PasswordEncoderInterface_. I`ve debuged the used authentication provider and noticed that the size of the database field is not long enough for the generated hash. So that`s the reason for the failed comparison.